# InputFile.PostedFile.ContentLength Units of measurement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, filesize, maxstringcontentlength

Please can you tell me the units measured by InputFile.PostedFile.ContentLength . I need to make sure the file is less than 500k.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unit of measurement = Byte.

```
1 Kilobyte (kB) = 2ˆ10 Byte = 1024 Bytes
```

Sample code testing for a file size of 15 KB:

```
const int maxFileLength = 15360; // 15KB = 1024 * 15

if(PictureFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > maxFileLength)
{

    MyResult.Text = String.Format("Your post has a size of {0:#,##0} bytes which
    exceeded the limit of {0:#,##0} bytes. Please upload a smaller file.",
    PictureFile.ContentLength, maxFileLength);
}
else
{
    // Save the file here
    MyResult.Text = "Thank you for posting."
}
```

In your case, as you want the file to be less than 500 KB, you should have this:

```
const int maxFileLength = 512000; // 500KB = 500 * 1024
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bytes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contentlength.aspx

> **HttpPostedFile.ContentLength**
>
> Gets the size of an uploaded file, in bytes.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

When i am uploading a template file of more than 1 mb its geting loaded for long time.my code is as below----

```
if (checkImagecount())
{
    //string imgFolder = Server.MapPath("/Userimages/" + emp_id.ToString().Trim() + "/Images/Browseimage/");
    string destinationImage = Server.MapPath("/master/" + emp_id.ToString().Trim() + "/Images/");
    string destination1 = Server.MapPath("/master/" + emp_id.ToString().Trim() + "/Images/");
    string imgFilename, fileExt = String.Empty;
    Response.Write(fileTemplateimage.PostedFile.ContentLength+"<br/>");
    Response.Write(fileTemplateimage.FileBytes.Length);
    Response.End();    
    if (fileTemplateimage.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 && fileTemplateimage.FileBytes.Length <= 1048576)
    {

        System.Drawing.Image uploadImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileTemplateimage.PostedFile.InputStream);
        float uploadImagewidth = uploadImage.PhysicalDimension.Width;
        float uploadImageheight = uploadImage.PhysicalDimension.Height;
else
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "failure", "alert('अपलोड फ़ाइल आकार 1 एमबी से अधिक नहीं होना चाहिए.');", true);
        divhide.Style.Add("display", "block");
        divUploadpanel.Style.Add("display", "block");
        fileTemplateimage.Focus();
```